# Query results are different in Codeigntier as compare to Mysql phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, codeigniter-3

Today i am facing a problem of creating dynamic query based on iterations in loop..below is my code.

**MY MODEL**

```
public function get_chapters_from_subject(){

if(COUNT($_REQUEST['subjects']) > 1){

   $this->db->where_in('question_modules', $_REQUEST['subjects']);
   $y = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix('multi_bind_question'));
   print_r($this->db->last_query());
   print_r($y->result()); 
 }
 else{
    echo "Only One ";
 }
}
```

After getting a different results i checked it by print a query generated by codeigniter. it is fine. the query is below

**Query generated after print, it look likes**

```
SELECT * FROM `app_multi_bind_question` WHERE `question_modules` IN('10+1 Math', '10+2 Math')
```

**Problem in result**

If i run the same query on mysql/phpmyadmin, then it returns 3 rows(corrected results). But when i print the query returned results in codeigniter model function as mentioned above, it returns only one record.

**PHPMYADMIN SCREENSHOT - CORRECTED RESULTS**
[image: Getting correct results here]
Plz help me! thanks in advance..

**After print result i got this only**
[image]

Comment: You can make your code more readable by `$this->db->where_in('question_modules', $_REQUEST['subjects']);` What's about your question, i seems to be if you ask different databases or  tables by CI and by phpadmin

Comment: @splash, it is a same table ..please check my query that i got after printing results..when i run it on phpmyadmin it gives me correct results, but when i run it throgh code as above, it returns diffrent results.

Comment: `echo count($y->result());`

Comment: It says only 1 record, but correct result should be 3..there are 3 records in database , After print the query, query look likes  : - SELECT * FROM `app_multi_bind_question` WHERE `question_modules` IN('10+1 Math', '10+2 Math')

Comment: phpmyadmin is the same interface to mysql process as any php library, CI is using (f.e. mysqli). Both just send a text query and receive a result of processing. I can't imagine where the result can be changed. The difference must be. It's not clear from the question, but must be :)

Comment: @splash58 , plz check the latest edit questions as per your suggested code

Comment: @splash58, wait i am going to attach a picture

Comment: @splash58, plz check i added a screenshot..hope it will helps you to find it

Comment: While you are at it, could you also post the result you get from your print_r($y->result()) for completeness.

Comment: Can you double check that the database you are connecting to in CI is the same one you are using in phpmyadmin. It's been known to happen where they can be different :)

Comment: Yes...i can re-check as per your suggestion & also i am going to post you what i receive in  ($y->results)..give me a few minutes

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, plz check latest edit..i added another screenshot

Comment: Sorry. i have no suggestion

Comment: as suggested - you should write a dummy text in your question title and print it out again - because i too think you are on the wrong database ;)

Comment: @RahulBajaj Have you checked the database config yet?

Comment: Try it in a different way `$sql = "SELECT * FROM app_multi_bind_question WHERE question_modules IN('10+1 Math', '10+2 Math')";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result();`

Comment: I will check @Riyenz

Comment: Getting same result

Comment: use `$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM 'app_multi_bind_question' WHERE 'question_modules' IN('10+1 Math', '10+2 Math'"); print_r($query->result_array());`

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with your database table (modules). change value as **10+2 Math** in your ***module table*** then result will come as expected.

You didn't get value because of value mismatch from those two table.

Module table as **10+2  Math** (It has two space)

In multi_bind_question table it stored as **10+2 Math** (It has one space)

There is no error in your code...

Hope it will; solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
public function get_chapters_from_subject(){

if(COUNT($_REQUEST['subjects']) > 1){

   $this->db->where_in('question_modules', $_REQUEST['subjects']);
   $y = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix('multi_bind_question'));
   print_r($this->db->last_query());
   print_r($y->result_array()); 
 }
 else{
    echo "Only One ";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion if your query is right then you should try this atleast:

```
public function get_chapters_from_subject(){
    if(COUNT($_REQUEST['subjects']) > 1){
        $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `app_multi_bind_question` WHERE `question_modules` IN('10+1 Math', '10+2 Math')");
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        print_r($this->db->last_query());
        return $query->result_array();
    }else{
         echo "Only One ";
    }
}
```